# Arduino Uno Driver - Windows 8 - Error while adding to memory

Tags: arduino, driver, windows-8.1

I have installed the Arduino IDE on my windows 8 laptop.
Now I'm trying to install the drivers for my Arduino Uno. I plugged in the Arduino with an USB cable. Then I went to the Device-Manager and tried to install the driver software that can be found in the Arduino IDE.

Then i get the Error: "Beim Hinzufügen des Treibers zum Speicher ist ein Problem aufgetreten", which means: "A problem was encountered while attempting to add the driver to the store.".

What am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have the same problem with an Arduino Mega 2650.
My installation fails with the error "A problem occurred while adding the driver to the store".

After some debugging I found out that the driver signature which Windows checks has expired on December 19, 2013.

I submitted an [issue](https://github.com/arduino/Arduino/issues/1755) and hope that the developers will resolve it soon.
Until then, I will try to [disable driver signature enforcement](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NM1MN8QZhnk) for this installation...

**Update**
Disabling the signature enforcement worked for me. I attached the Arduino, opened the device manager, chose "Update device driver" and pointed it to the "driver" subdirectory of my Arduino IDE.

Comment: i think this should work, i solved by running windows xp in a virtual machine :)